# Wrapping Angular content in conditional outter tags

Tags: angular

I would like to create and Angular component that when I specify

```
<app-title level="1">some text</app-title>
<app-title level="2">some other text</app-title>
```

it generates

```
<h1>some text</h1>
<h2>some other text</h2>
```

I've tried

```
<h1 *ngIf="isLevel1"><ng-content></ng-content></h1>
<h2 *ngIf="!isLevel1"><ng-content></ng-content></h2>
```

but ng-content only renders in one of the tags, not both.

How can I make the content appear inside an h1 or h2 tag based on the level?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `select` attribute of `ng-content` and getting rid of the *ngIf:

```html
<h1><ng-content select="[level=1]"></ng-content></h1>
<h2><ng-content select="[level=2]"></ng-content></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-template is the answer.
First put the ng-content inside an ng-template.  Then embed your template in both conditional tags.

```
<ng-template #contentTemplate><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
<h1 *ngIf="isLevel1"><ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="contentTemplate"></ng-template></h1>
<h2 *ngIf="!isLevel1"><ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="contentTemplate"></ng-template></h2>
```